# CKEditor: Remove the MagicLine plugin

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, text-editor, magicline

I've been trying to remove the red line in CKEditor that allows you to insert a paragraph, and it's stubbornly refusing to remove itself.

Adding this code in the javascript that creates it:

```
CKEDITOR.replace(target,{
    removePlugins: 'magicline',
    ... 
});
```

Still has the red bar show up.

Adding the following line to CKEditor's config.js

```
config.removePlugins = 'magicline';
```

Still has the red bar show up.

I have tried several permutations of `MagicLine`, `magicline`, `Magic Line`, `magic-line`, `Magic-Line` in each spot, and in each time, the red bar stubbornly refuses to be gone.

I'm sure I'm simply missing the proper name for the plugin.  What is it.

Comment: Just tried removing the `/plugins/magicline/` folder. The Magic Line IS STILL THERE.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I also removed the folder and its freaking still there, something is weird..

Comment: My solution was to switch to a different WISYWYG editor: Summernote.

Comment: Although I recognize that this doesn't help your problem. Sorry.

Comment: Allright, thanks for the answer. Too deep in this project to switch though. Still very weird. I think it must somehow be bundled together or concatenated in some main file somehow..

Answer (score 4):

In `config.js` add these lines:

```
config.removePlugins = 'magicline';
CKEDITOR.config.magicline_color = '#0000FF';
```

Comment: Changing the color is unnecessary since the plugin is "no longer there".

Answer (score 0):

in the `ckeditor.js` file 
find this line 
`CKEDITOR.config.plugins = 'dialogui,dialog,....,magicline,...'`
remove `magicline` from the list.

Comment: I was working with Python/Django project I just copied the `ckeditor.js` file and put it inside my `static` directory with the same folder hierarchy
` static/ ckeditor/ckeditor/ckeditor.js `

I did so to override the ckeditor.js file that comes with the original package.
Hope that makes sense.